# How to Redirect non-existing data page to Page Not Found in Codeignitor?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

I am trying to redirect the pages when the data does not exist/ page not exist to 404 Page Not Found. I can redirect the pages to 404 successfully through routes,

```
e.g. www.testing.com/jhdbgkj => go to 404 page is okay
```

However, I've found that when the url contains more than one section, it fails to redirect:

```
www.testing/product/dhjbg => cannot redirect to 404 page
```

I know that I can redirect to 404 page in the Controller if the passed param is not found, which is what I'm currently doing. (As the passed param is used in fetching some data, I cannot just set the 'product/(:any)' in routes to go to the 404 page ) However, I wonder if there's some faster way in redirecting to 404 page all in once, instead of blocking in Controller one by one... Or is that not possible?

Another question is that, is it possible to redirect php error page to our own custom 404 Page, displaying the error page in a better way? Thank you.

Routes:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "common/pageNotFound";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can design your own 404 page by redirecting

```
$route['404_override'] = 'my404';
```

your controller be like

```
<?php class My404 extends CI_Controller { public function __construct() { parent::__construct(); } public function index() { $this->output->set_status_header('404'); $this->load->view('err404');//loading in custom error view } }
```